# String can't find the value in a same line

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "This is the test and new paragraph...\n";

if($str=~m/paragraph/gi) # First Loop
{
    if($str=~m/test/gi) # Second Loop 
    {
        print "Ok...\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Not Ok...\n";
    }
}

if($str=~m/test/i) #it doesn't prints the value

Output is: Not Ok...

if($str=~m/test/gi) #it prints the value

Output is: Ok...
```

In above case if the string found the `paragraph` value and the second loop couldn't find the `test` value. However in the second loop if we inserted the global `g` it can.

Could you please someone can explain me whats happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [How to get a regex to start from the beginning of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4587539/2173773)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the global `/g` modifier here. You need to check whether one string contains another, not to find all occurrences of one in another. And `if` statements aren't loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/g` is used for finding all matches of a pattern. It doesn't make sense to alter the pattern between matches. Generally speaking, `if (/.../g)` makes no sense and should be replaced with `if (/.../)`.

There are advanced uses for `if (/\G.../gc)`, but that's different. `if (/.../g)` only makes sense if you're unrolling a while loop. (e.g. `while (1) { ...; last if !/.../g; ... }`).

---

Here's what's happening in this specific circumstance:

Because you signaled you wanted to find all matches (by using `/g`), the position at which to start matching is set to the end of the match (denoted by `^` below).

```
This is the test and new paragraph...
                         ---------^
```

You can see this using `pos`.

```
$ perl -e'
    my $str = "This is the test and new paragraph...";
    if ($str =~ /paragraph/g) {
       CORE::say pos($str) // 0;
       if ($str =~ /test/g) {
          CORE::say pos($str) // 0;
       }
    }
'
34
```

The subsequent `m/test/gi` doesn't match because `test` does not appear at or after the position at which the last match ended.

The solution is to simply remove the `g` modifier from you match operators.

```
$ perl -e'
    my $str = "This is the test and new paragraph...";
    if ($str =~ /paragraph/) {
       CORE::say pos($str) // 0;
       if ($str =~ /test/) {
          CORE::say pos($str) // 0;
       }
    }
'
0
0
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl):

> Global matching
>
> The final two modifiers we will discuss here, //g and //c , concern multiple matches. The modifier //g stands for global matching and allows the matching operator to match within a string as many times as possible. In scalar context, successive invocations against a string will have //g jump from match to match, keeping track of position in the string as it goes along. You can get or set the position with the pos() function.

In the first test, you're using the global flag, then the position of cursor is memorized, so the second match doesn't find `test` because it is before `paragraph`.

You have to remove the global flag from the first match.

```
my $str = "This is the test and new paragraph...\n";

if ($str =~ /paragraph/i) {
    if ($str =~ /test/i) {
        print "Ok...\n";
    } else {
        print "Not Ok...\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks.